# Jammit fails to package tinyMCE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, jammit

When I load the page with tinyMCE I get the following errors:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/users//langs/en.js"
en.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/users//themes/advanced/editor_template.js"

The path seems to be all wrong but I have no idea how to debug this.

Edit: as requested I am adding some code

application.js

```
tinyMCE.init({
          content_css : '/stylesheets/tinyMCE.css?bogus=1306384393',
          editor_selector : 'mceEditor',
          font_size_style_values : '10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px',
          language : 'en',
          mode : 'textareas',
          theme : 'advanced',
          theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'bold,italic,underline,fontsizeselect,forecolor,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent, justifycenter,justifyright,justifyleft, blockquote',
          theme_advanced_buttons2 : '',
          theme_advanced_buttons3 : '',
          theme_advanced_containers_default_align : 'left',
          theme_advanced_font_sizes : '10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px',
          theme_advanced_resizing : false,
          theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
          theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top'
          });
```

jammit asset.yml:

```
embed_assets: off
javascripts:



workspace:
      - public/javascripts/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js
      - public/javascripts/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.js
      - public/javascripts/rails.validations.js
      - public/javascripts/cocoon.js
      - public/javascripts/jquery_plugins/count_char/jquery.jqEasyCharCounter.js
      - public/javascripts/jquery_plugins/jquery.truncate/jquery.truncate.js         
      - public/javascripts/jquery_plugins/jquery.watermark-3.1.3/jquery.watermark.js  
      - public/javascripts/jquery_plugins/jquery.elastic-1.6.10/jquery.elastic.source.js
      - public/javascripts/swfobject.js
      - public/javascripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
      - public/javascripts/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.js
      - public/javascripts/jquery_plugins/jquery.webcam/jquery.webcam.js
      - public/javascripts/jquery_plugins/paulelliott-In-Field-Labels-jQuery-Plugin-796bc1f/src/jquery.infieldlabel.js
      - public/javascripts/scribd_view.js
      - public/javascripts/rails.js
      - public/javascripts/application.js



    stylesheets:
      common:
          - public/stylesheets/blueprint/screen.css
          - public/stylesheets/jquery-ui/*.css
          - public/stylesheets/jquery.fileupload-ui.css
          - public/stylesheets/tinyMCE.css
          - public/stylesheets/application.css
      ie_any:
          - public/stylesheets/ie_fixes.css
      ie_before_v8: 
          - public/stylesheets/blueprint/ie.css
```

Thanks for any help,
-Matteo

Comment: Please provide some code so that one is able to answer........

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this list of relevant tinymce settings concerning paths: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#Paths.2FURLs_are_incorrect.2C_I_want_absolute.2Frelative_URLs.3F

Comment: this is about paths on links created in tinymce, not pathes to the tinymce files itself